# Calculate commission percentage based on input amount

Tags: logarithms, regression

I want to create a function that returns a commission percentage (y) bases on an input amount (x). My math is a bit rusty (to say the least), but I recall that this should be a logarithmic regression that approaches a certain value (and never surpasses it).

The data is as follows:

- x1: 500, f(x1): 5%
- x2: 2500, f(x2): 3%
- x3: 10000, f(x3) : 1%
- inf, f(inf) : ≈ 0.5 %

I apologise for being a complete newb in math, but I hope this makes sense and someone can help me out!

Comment: Basically you have the regression function $y_i=a\cdot e^{b\cdot x_i}+0.005 \Rightarrow y_i-0.005=a\cdot e^{b\cdot x_i} $. Taking logarithm: $\ln(y_i-0.005)=\ln(a)+b\cdot x_i$ Now you can apply a linear regression.

Comment: Thanks @callculus for your prompt reply! Not sure if i'm looking for linear regression. 
Imagine that you charge a commission (y) over amount (x), for value x closing in on 0, y will become a horizontal asymptote near y = 5, and for any value x that is coming near 10.000 will close in on asymptote y = 0.5, this basically means that between value x = 1 and x = 10.000 there will be a certain decreasing value for y between 5 to 0.5 respectively. Thanks again!

Comment: I've created a small sketch (looks a bit crappy) but I believe thats the graph i'm looking for https://www.a-tech-company.com/temp/example-graph.png